# Switching PMOS issue

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

i wanted to make a nand gate circuit for driving a few amp loads using pmfets.

in my desgin im using DMP4010SK3Qfets, and any transistor thats capable of handeling 24+ volts on the collector. my problem starts with multisim, i imported the mfet and got results drastically different to what i got with falstad (in that both turn on). im guessing either i've imported the spice model incorrectly or these something else at work that i've missed.

i wanted to verify it in real life and got a board made from jlbpcb with a SSTA06HZGT116 as the transistor and in testing that with a row of leds (about a 400ma load) they both turn on.

have i gone about this the wrong way ?
i wanted to keep the circuit idea the same as opposed to having drivers and a stmfx to control it.

[image: Falstad mfet]

[image: Multisim]

Comment: I see pin numbers on your FETs not S,D,G. Check you haven't swapped source and drain : taking due note of the body diode.

Comment: Eyyyy, you were on the ball, appreciate picking up on the dumb mistake.
im fairly new to reading the spice documentation, in the text file it has this line

.SUBCKT DMP4010SK3Q 10 20 30 
*     TERMINALS:  D  G  S
does this mean that the terms are as follows
D=1 node, G=2 node and S =3rd node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can’t figure out what the circuit should do, but I know what it actually does. Here I see one input and two outputs if I consider the LEDs to be that. Either one is lit or the other. He does this well. What would be the goal?

SW OFF:

[image]

SW ON:

[image]

Comment: yep correct, same as mine falsad sim. sorry if the multisim one is a tad unreadable im fairely new to using it

Comment: No problem, I see there was a problem with the FET model.

Comment: could i ask what program you're using ?

Comment: I have TINA 9.3 on my PC and the [TINA-TI](https://www.ti.com/tool/TINA-TI) (9.3) version.

Comment: cheers mate, appreciate it